# How to rename existing files using a batch file for backup purpose?

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, rename

```
pkzip25 -add=all -dir=current -silent -locale -exclude=DistData.zip -exclude=extract.bat -exclude=run.bat -exclude=pkzip25.exe -exclude=extracted.txt -exclude=zipped.txt -exclude=.\STORE DistData.zip *.*
pkzip25 -view -directories DistData.zip >zipped.txt

copy DistData.zip ..\BKX\DistData_1.zip
cd ..\BKX
rename DistData_1.zip DistData_2.zip 
rename DistData_2.zip DistData_3.zip
rename DistData_3.zip DistData_4.zip
rename DistData_4.zip DistData_5.zip
```

Comment: Can you phrase your question in the form of a question?!?!

Answer (score 2):

```
rename DistData_1.zip DistData_2.zip 
rename DistData_2.zip DistData_3.zip
rename DistData_3.zip DistData_4.zip
rename DistData_4.zip DistData_5.zip
```

Is wrong, you have to use the opposite order and delete the last one first:

```
del DistData_5.zip
rename DistData_4.zip DistData_5.zip
rename DistData_3.zip DistData_4.zip
rename DistData_2.zip DistData_3.zip
rename DistData_1.zip DistData_2.zip
```

and maybe also move DistData.zip instead of copy, so it does not exist if you create a new zipfile.

```
move DistData.zip ..\BKX\DistData_1.zip
```

But I don't know if this was your question/problem.

Edit:
If you want to keep 5 zipfiles (instead of 4), I suggest the following:

```
del DistData.zip >NUL 2>&1
pkzip25 -add=all -dir=current -silent -locale -exclude=DistData.zip -exclude=extract.bat -exclude=run.bat -exclude=pkzip25.exe -exclude=extracted.txt -exclude=zipped.txt -exclude=.\STORE DistData.zip *.*
pkzip25 -view -directories DistData.zip >zipped.txt

move DistData.zip ..\BKX
cd ..\BKX
del DistData_5.zip
rename DistData_4.zip DistData_5.zip
rename DistData_3.zip DistData_4.zip
rename DistData_2.zip DistData_3.zip
rename DistData_1.zip DistData_2.zip 
rename DistData.zip DistData_1.zip
```

This way you always have 5 backup copies.